# How to connect to ib_sync in Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, ib-insync

How do you successfully set up an ib_insync connection in Google Colab?

Have tried:

`pip install ib_insync`

which runs successfully. then:

```
from ib_insync import * 
util.startLoop() 
ib = IB()
ib = IB( ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, clientId=1)
```

Which results in:

```
API connection failed: ConnectionRefusedError(111, "Connect call failed ('127.0.0.1', 7497)")
Make sure API port on TWS/IBG is open
```

I have seen other related questions indicating one needs to set up a local runtime ([colab reference document](https://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html)), however, I have not been able to successfully run this code (specifically receive an invalid syntax error when I get to step to run `jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws` in colab. I normally access ib_insync via jupyter lab.

Thanks for considering

Comment: I do not know bro, also have the same question